# What does it mean "go and ride the sun away"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

What does it mean "go and ride the sun away" ?

Comment: It doesn't really mean anything, is this from a poem or song? Could you provide a link to the text? It might make sense with a bit more context.

Comment: Yes, it's from song: Go and hide and run away!
Run away,
Run and find something better!
Go and ride the sun away!
Run away, like it's simple,
Like it's right...

Comment: I _guess_ it could mean "let's go and ride until the sun goes down", figuratively saying you "use the warmth of the sun for pleasure", using it up until there is no more sunlight. But that is literary criticism, and we cannot know if this meaning makes sense unless we know more context. If I take six words from a random song, chances are nobody can understand any meaning in them.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about interpreting the lyrics of a song. More information about on-topic song lyric questions can be found [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/why-only-some-questions-asking-lyrics-meaning-are-off-topic-and-not-all) and [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-song-meanings). Also, when people ask for clarification (such as, "Where did you find this quote?"), it's often better to edit your question than reply in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

**From the song: Still Hurting by The Last Five Years**

> Go and hide and run away
>
> Run away, run and find something better
>
> Go and ride the sun away
>
> Run away like it's simple
>
> Like it's right...

Song lyrics are always difficult to explain, they often just describe a mental image without meaning anything that should be taken literally. For example, Beck's song *Loser* has the lyrics "don't believe everything that you breathe, you get a parking violation and a maggot on your sleeve" which is complete nonsense but sounds nice.

The lyrics "go and ride the sun away" should be understood as "ride the sun like a horse and travel far away". Less literally it might mean "drive away into the sunset and be happy", the idea of riding off into the sunset comes from how Wild West movies used to end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvoNK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are idiomatic phrases which the song's lyric seems to be playing with.

VERB... the day away

VERB... the night away

For example:

*Dance the night away.

Sleep the day away.*

in which "away" conveys the idea that a person has spent the entire time doing the VERB. There is a sense of *abandoning oneself* or *giving oneself over* to the activity (dancing, sleeping, etc).

To *ride the sun away*, in light of this idiom, could mean "to spend the entire day riding". Ride and ride and ride.

There is a second locative meaning of "away", that is, "into the distance".

*They drove away and were never seen again.*

*They ran away.*

Both of these meanings of *away* coalesce in the lyric, whose message is to *abandon yourself to the idea of escaping from a situation.*